# How to know what frameworks or libraries a web app uses

Tags: jquery, ajax, web, frontend

I'm just about to "inherit" a full web app, the former developers didn't leave any documentation behind besides the one in the code.

I'd like to know, first of all, what libraries/frameworks they used on the front end, as that is the least of my expertise.

Where should I look at to discover the used libraries?

Comment: `package.json` (if there is one) and utilize a source map explorer

Comment: You can try checking which external files are loaded by your application. Their names usually give you a good idea of which frameworks/libraries were used.

Comment: Can you please recommend a source map explorer?

Comment: It depends on the format in which the web app will be given to you.

Comment: Webz haz toolz: builtwith; stackshare; whatruns.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Firefox plugin Wappalyzer. I detects front and backend web-technologies used on websites.

https://www.wappalyzer.com/